# Android Accessibility in RecyclerView - Move through items with SwitchAccess Services

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility

I'm trying to implement Accessibility Services in my App. I have a RecyclerView among other components and I want that when a user is navigating through the content with SwitchAccess service and focus the RecyclerView it can move the focus item by item inside the RecyclerView. I can only do that the entire RecyclerView got the focus but not the elements inside it.
I tried putting `android:focusable="true"`, `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`, `android:screenReaderFocusable="true"` on the item view, also setting `android:importantForAccessibility="yes"` in the RecyclerView and also I tried some code snippets to set setAccessibilityDelegate to RecyclerView but none of that worked for me.

This is my current RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_search_history"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_latest_search" />
```

This is my Adapter:

```
class HotelSearchAdapter(private val mHotelSearchHistory: List<HotelSearchItem>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<HotelSearchAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): HotelSearchAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val binding =
        ItemSearchHistoryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HotelSearchAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    with(holder) {
        with(mHotelSearchHistory[position]) {
            holder.itemView.tag = position

            holder.itemView.contentDescription = "Search ${position + 1}: $hotelName on $date"

            itemBinding.textviewHotelName.text = hotelName
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}

override fun getItemCount() = mHotelSearchHistory.size

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return mHotelSearchHistory[position].id.toLong()
}

inner class ViewHolder(val itemBinding: ItemSearchHistoryBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root)
}
```

And this is the item view:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:screenReaderFocusable="true">

//... Some TextViews here ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```